# PhoneGap Lat Long Distance calculation

Tags: html, sqlite, cordova

I have created a PhoneGap app so it's database is using HTML Storage. I have a table of locations which include their lat and long. I then have the users current location and need to find the closest 3 locations.

How would I go about this mathematically? Will I need to convert the lat long values or can they be directly comparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the easiest way to do that is convert the distance between the coordinates to kms and then loop through the coordinates you have and figure out which ones you want. It's simple math, you can read more about it [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) if you want.

```
getDistanceBetweenCoordinates:function(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2){

        var distance = (3958*3.1415926*Math.sqrt((lat2-lat1)*(lat2-lat1) + Math.cos(lat2/57.29578)*Math.cos(lat1/57.29578)*(lng2-lng1)*(lng2-lng1))/180);   
        //console.log("distance:" + distance);

        return Number(distance); 

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense, but is there a way to do this within the database query?